# numerical integration of MATLAB on my function give me many numbers not a single number

Tags: matlab, integral

Numerical integration of MATLAB on my function give me many numbers not a single number. I'm not good at MatLaB, so I don't know the reason. Is there anyone who can help me ?

this is my function.

```
function [ y ] = SucP( l,a,P,D,r,th );

d=2./a;
Ehd=integral(@(x)x.^d.*exp(-x),0,inf);
gam=gamma(1-d);
C1=1./(1+th.*(r/D).^a);
C2=1./(1+th.*P.*(r/D).^a);
hypgeo1=hypergeom([1,2],[2-d],th.*(r./D).^a.*C1);
hypgeo2=hypergeom([1,2],[2-d],th.*P.*(r./D).^a.*C2);
y=exp(-l.*pi.*(th).^d.*r.^2.*P.^d.*Ehd.*gam-C1+C2+th./(1-d).*r.^2.*(r./D).^(a-2).*(C1.^2.*hypgeo1-P.^d.*C2.^2.*hypgeo2));

end
```

And I want to integrate

```
fun=@(l,a,P,D,r,z)SucP(l,a,P,D,r,2.^z-1);
y=integral(@(z)fun(l,a,P,D,r,z),0,inf);
```

But this integration give me following result.

```
Columns 1 through 6

   0.999869167524854   0.998589370430984   0.994817933624792   0.987704371328770   0.976976845412355   0.962748430805626

  Columns 7 through 12

   0.945394762911001   0.925627034788835   0.904532141053543   0.883378353636190   0.863363119639727   0.845589211136565 ....

Columns 145 through 150

             NaN                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN


ans =

   NaN
```

Is there anyone who can help me ?

Comment: Looks like your output represents the values of a Cumulative Distribution Function, taken at various values of a random variable. If, as i think, you are trying to integrate a Probability density function, the value you are looking for is one of the values you get in the output. I cannot tell you which  one though, if you don't give us your input Data

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment. Yes, the function SucP(l,a,P,D,r,2^z-1) is Prob(X>z) for some random variable X. So I want to calculate the expectation of X. And (l,a,P,D,r) is a parameter. I used (0.5,3,0.2,10,2) as a parameter.

Comment: Ok. If i denote by f the Probability density function associated with your random variable, you are currectly calculating the integral from z to infinity of f(x)dx. But what you need, in order to calculate the expectation, is to calculate the integral, from -infinity to +infinity, of x*f(x)dx.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my theory is not wrong. my integration means expectation, exactly. This is just problem about matlab, not math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of :

**1)** You must get rid of those NaN values. The reason why they appear is the following :

You're trying to integrate your function

```
SucP(l,a,P,D,r,2.^z-1)
```

From `z=0` to `infinity`. But, from a certain value of `z` , `2^z-1` will be bigger than the biggest number matlab can deal with.

What you need to do to avoid that is to change the bounds of your integration so that `2^z-1` never goes above realmax (which is the biggest value MATLAB can handle).

The upper bound of your integration will be :

```
Upperbound=log(realmax)/log(2)-4;
```

**2)** You must change your declaration of the `fun` dunction you declare to :

```
fun=@(z)SucP(l,a,P,D,r,2.^z-1);
```

And then call :

```
Y=integral(fun,0,log(realmax)/log(2)-4);
```

Comment: you are right. After I put 100 instead of inf, matlab gave me a single number not a NaN. But log(realmax)/log(2)-1 does not work. this gave me NaN again.

Comment: Try with log(realmax)/log(2)-4

Comment: I am using MATLAB R2014a.

Comment: Try with -4 instead of -1 as i told you

Comment: (problem is that the value might get even bigger INSIDE the function, depending on the parameters (l,alP,D,r), meaning we have to decrease the max value again)